# Chaining security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, network-security-groups

I have been looking all around why something which I believe should work, does not.
Here's a breakdown

- I have a bastion with publicly assigned IP in that's security group enables all **egress** traffic. There's also this, sort of a point to the question:

```yaml
  FooSSHIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 22
      ToPort: 22
      GroupId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${FooStackName}-AdminSecurityGroup"
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref BastionSecurityGroup
      Description: Enables SSH to FooService
```

So I am trying to allow connections coming from `BastionSecurityGroup@22` to reach another security group that's called `AdminSecurityGroup` fro `FooStack`.

`AdminSecurityGroup` can be found below. Is is obviously empty, but bear with me. The point was to have a security group that can be linked somewhere to enable SSH access.

```yaml
  AdminSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: >-
        For FooService admin access.
        Grants access to EC2 instances over SSH.
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VpcStackName}-VPCId"
```

Anyway, that group above is later on linked to SecurityGroup being **finally** referenced in `AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate`. It's definition is below:

```yaml
  ServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable Client and Admin access
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${VpcStackName}-VPCId"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !Ref ClientPort
          ToPort: !Ref ClientPort
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ClientSecurityGroup
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref AdminSecurityGroup
```

As you can see there's also `ClientSecurityGroup` that follows the same pattern.

Finally, questions are:

1. Does it make sense?
2. Why does it not work? By my knowledge, having security group like so should result in routing traffic through ENI. But somehow it does not.
3. Funny thing is that if I replace `AdminSecurityGroup` with `ServerSecurityGroup`, for bastion, connection is possible. Obviously that is followed by removing `AdminSecurityGroup` and `ClientSecurityGroup` from `FooStack` (no point in having those anymore).
4. Why everything kicks in if all security groups of `Foo` are referenced inside of `LaunchTemplate` ?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Decent separation and ability to track those security groups. System is quite large, so I'd like to be able to know what is linked and where. This FooService we're talking about will be used in at least 4 other services so I wanted to have a single `ClientSecurityGroup` to link there. On the other hand `AdminSecurityGroup` is just for bastion but I figured it will make sense to have things consistent.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein what if I keep seperation but remove references inside of `ServerSecurityGroup` to both `Admin...` and `Client..`

PS. I haven't posted entire `ServerSecurityGroup` TBH. There are self references to enable cluster communication of FooService.

Comment: I cannot see a reason to have a Security Group with no defined ingress/egress. There is no concept of 'chaining' security groups. From what I can see, you would need one security group for the Bastion (port 22 in from a whitelist of IPs), and then a security group for the app that allows inbound connections from the Bastion security group.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help and suggestions :)